# How to create dynamic JSON Object in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

My requirement is to create dynamic JSON Object on a fly and here is my Java code which I wrote earlier and it works fine in Eclipse but when I added the same code in Beanshell sampler, it is throwing an error. Is there anything different which I need to do in Beanshell? Any suggestion is welcome, Thanks

```
 JSONObject[] innerObject = new JSONObject[3];
 innerObject[0].put("fullName", "Jason Hopes");
 innerObject[1].put("firstName", "Jason");
 innerObject[2].put("lastName", "Hopes");
```

Error is

```
 2020-11-14 20:51:11,963 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: Exception isjava.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke method put on null value
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the library which provides these `org.json.JSONObject` and `org.json.JSONArray` to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) along with its dependencies (if any) to JMeter Classpath and restart JMeter to pick the .jar up. Presumably it's [this one](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json)

Also be aware that [since JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to use JSR223 Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting, [Groovy has built-in JSON support](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html) so you won't need any extra libraries

The relevant code would be something like:

```
def payload = []
payload.add([fullName:'Jason Hopes'])
payload.add([firstName: 'Jason'])
payload.add([lastName: 'Hopes'])

log.info(new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(payload).toPrettyString())
```

[image]

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thanks, Dmitry for the response but I already have the required jar files in the lib folder. Normal JSONObject and JSONArray is working fine, the issue is when JSON object is initialized with array i.e. JSONObject[]. 

Other solution which you provided about using Groovy scripting, I am trying to add JSONArray inside JSONObject, can we do it using Groovy?  I already have the Java code written in Eclipse which is working fine, I just need to reuse the same code in Jmeter.  Can you recommend which approach should I go with?

Comment: The JSON request mentioned in the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64691804/how-can-we-change-the-order-of-json-object-using-java - This is what I want to create on a fly with dynamic values.

Comment: Also, I put my code under Try- Catch and here is the exact exception which I am getting "2020-11-14 20:51:11,963 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: Exception isjava.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke method put on null value" 

I have updated my question with this information